# codeblocks can't open g++

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I'm currently running ubuntu 13.10 with codeblocks and when I try to build it comes up with this message:

```
g++    -c /home/rhys/Documents/Progamming/c++/Class_private/main.cpp -o /home/rhys/Documents/Progamming/c++/Class_private/main.o 
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open g++    -c /home/rhys/Documents/Progamming/c++/Class_private/main.cpp -o /home/rhys/Documents/Progamming   /c++/Class_private/main.o

Process terminated with status 127 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

It used to work fine but it does not work now, I have downloaded the build-essential, then the gcc complier which it is set to in the settings.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check "Settings -> Environment -> General settings -> Shell to run commands in:" and make sure it says "/bin/sh -c" you must have the -c argument. Either this or it could a file path problem with the compiler or source files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set the access for your files and/or your whole working directory. So go there, and change permission with chmod:

> cd /home/rhys/Documents/Progamming/c++/Class_private/
>
> chmod 755 *

If this not works maybe you should check if g++ is accessible. Run:

> g++ --version

See if it prints the information or another error.

Another solution could be to open Code::Blocks as a superuser and then try again as you normally did.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I tried doing the 'chmod 755*' and it came up with the message 'chmod: missing operand after ‘755*’ and tried typing in 'g++ -version' and came up with the message 'g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-version’
g++: fatal error: no input files'. Tried opening codeblocks as a super user but it still has the same problem, thanks.

Comment: You should put a space between permission number and operand "*": 'chmod 755 *'